# MediaSource API, buffering strange behavior

Tags: javascript, html5-video, media-source

I'm testing a streaming web application that uses MediaSourceAPI. Everything works fine, however when i stream big files (i.e 240MB or more), the buffer of the video has a strange behavior. To be more clear i attached three images you can check. My script creates a mediaSource object, then it calls addSourceBuffer and then it calls appendBuffer many time as there are chunks to append. I think that i do not configure well the buffer and so the mediaSource API use a default value for the buffer length.

Could you help me please?

Visit https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!category-topic/chrome/report-a-problem-and-get-troubleshooting-help/windows8/Stable/0igRzDJQ7ds

Answer (score 0):

There is a max limit on the size of the SourceBuffers, maybe you're exceeding those? When they exceed the limits, the browsers will start evicting buffer segments according to some defined algorithm.

If you are appending as much data to the source buffers as you can, you might want to introduce a limit. E.g. for us, when playing HD video at 4.5mps, we could have a buffer size of about 3-4 minutes before we saw some odd behaviour (e.g. segments being evicted in front of the videos currentTime)